# Installing QGIS on Mac OS 10.7. "The GDAL framework is required.", and yet I have it

Tags: qgis, installation

what did I miss? I'm trying to install QGIS on my MacBook (Mac OS 10.7). I'm following these instructions: https://sites.google.com/site/eospansite/qgis-installation/installing-qgis-1-6-on-macosx

It says to first install GDAL following these instructions: https://sites.google.com/site/eospansite/installinggdalonmacosx

I installed GDAL but when I come to install QGIS I click on the QuantumGIS.pkg and it opens the install dialogue box but with a warning "The GDAL framework is required."

I know that GDAL is there, I can see it in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/ so I wonder if exporting the path didn't work. Anyone know how to check that? Or anyone know of anything else I may have overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: Did you use the Kyng Chaos installer for the GDAL framework?  If so, do you have a current enough version installed?  I frequently use William's installers and have never had a problem with QGIS on OSX.

Comment: Which version of QGIS did you get?

Comment: @R.K. I just clicked on the link on the instruction page above, which says 'QGIS 1.7.1-3 for Lion and Snow Leopard' The readme that came with the pkg is dated 2011-10-30.

Comment: @DavidF I don't think I used the Kyng Chaos installer. I just downloaded the files from that website and used Mac's own installer to try and install by opening the .pkg files. Not sure if that's what you mean. Where would I find William's installers? (I'm completely new to GIS, sorry if these are basic queries.)

Comment: @R.K. Ok, I discovered a newer version (v1.8.0-2) of QGIS here (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis), and it's installed fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Okay. Will update my answer. Good to know that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the latest version of [QGIS KyngChaos installers](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). They're usually the most stable and up-to-date ones for QGIS on OSX.

I think you exported the wrong path. You mentioned

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDL.framework/
```

when it should be

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/
```

Or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just a typo. It's at GDAL.framework, and that's what I tried to export it as. I've edited my question to fix it.